# Remove certain text from textarea in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a little input on the best way to remove a certain word or phrase in a text area.  I have an input field entitled `input`. I want to search that area for the word that is put into a form field called `name` and then removed from `input`.  None of the code I have tried works, and most search results yield irrelephant.

```
function delete() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var textarea = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var data = textarea.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (textarea.substr(i, data) == name) {
            textarea.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried earlier with no luck.

Comment: and what is the code that you have tried

Comment: It didn't work and more of just hackjob so it's not much of a starting place.

Comment: you tagged jQuery... Why don't you use it ?

Comment: @Brewal I'm not familiar with jQuery enough to come up with it.  But I'm not opposed to using it if it's a relatively easy solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do,  but this is the correct code: (*there are many mistakes in your code*)

```
function deleteValue() {  //instead of "delete"
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var textarea = document.getElementById("result");  //intead of "input"
    var data = textarea.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data.substr(i, data) == name.value) {
            textarea.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Some points to consider:

- Change your text input name from `input` to something else because it is a `tag name`.
- You can't have a function name `delete` because it is a reserved word in javascript. use something else like `deleteValue`.

**UPDATE**:

I think this is what you are looking for..

```
function deleteValue() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var textarea = document.getElementById("result");
    textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(name.value, "");
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/NmSAG/1/)**

Comment: I'm not able to get the `textarea.value.replace(name.value, "");` working.  If I change the `textarea.value =` to a word I can get it to display, but if I keep it that way it doesn't make any changes.

Comment: @SethEarby I changed the `id` value of textarea.. check

Comment: I did as well, but still nothing.  The only difference between my code and the fiddle is that my name field is a form input entitled name.

Comment: @SethEarby are you sure your input title is : `<input type="text" id="name" name="whatever" />` ?

Comment: It was correct, curly braces are the bane of my existence.  Thanks for everything guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `replaceAll` function to String object. If you want to remove all occurrences of specific text.

```
(function() {   
    if (!String.replaceAll) {
        String.prototype.replaceAll = function replaceAll(replace, value) {
            return this.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'), value);
        };
}
}());
```

And modify `delete` function should look like this:

```
function deleteValue() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var textarea = document.getElementById('result');
    var data = textarea.value;
    textarea.value = textarea.value.replaceAll(name.value, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the jQuery solution (I provide it since you tagged jQuery) :

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfS64/1/)**

```
// to execute code when the page is entierly loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    // click event on the button
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        // get the content of the #result textarea
        val = $('#result').val();
        // remove all occurence of content of #name in #result
        $('#result').val(val.replace($('#name').val(), ""));
    });
});
```